# Code in assembly to access the 2nd value element of the linked list

Tags: assembly, x86

Any help is appreaciate, I cannot firgure it out for many days :(.

I have a set of linked list.
Eg: 0,0,0,0,0
or 1,1,1,1,1
or -10,-5,0,5,10

I can access the first element of the linked list fine!
The 1st one the stack, but the 2nd one is not on the stack memory.

Here is my code to access the 1st value element of the linked list

```
__declspec(naked) int valueLink(struct Node *head) {
__asm{
           PUSH EBX

           MOV EBX, [ESP+8] //get the address of the first element of linked list on the stack

           MOV EAX, [EBX] // move the value to EAX

           POP EBX
           ret
         }
        }
```

I will got the correct output like:

The list contains -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, and the positive sum is 0.
your result is -1.

The list contains 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, and the positive sum is 5.
your result is 1

The list contains -10, -5, 0, 5, 10, and the positive sum is 15.
your result is -10

But now I wan to access the 2nd value of the linked list, I modify the code -->

```
__declspec(naked) int valueLink(struct Node *head) {
__asm{
          PUSH EBX

          MOV EBX, [ESP+8] //get the address of the first element of linked list on the stack

          MOV EAX, [EBX+4] // move the second value to EAX

          POP EBX
          ret
         }
       }
```

I will got the wrong value !!! Please help ?!?!

The list contains -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, and the positive sum is 0.
your result is 4760640

The list contains 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, and the positive sum is 5.
your result is 4760920

The list contains -10, -5, 0, 5, 10, and the positive sum is 15.
your result is 4769096

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a structure for the nodes in the linked list defined in your example. Assuming that a structure named node is defined with members *next* and *value*, then the syntax for the node and to add a value from a node that ebx points to is:

```
node    struct
next    dd      ?
value   dd      ?
node    ends
;       ...
        add     eax,node.value[ebx]
;       ...
```

Comment: hi rcgldr, thanks for helping. I just add the structure name node to the code. But my assembly code still not working with "node.value" syntax. I want to move the second value to register EAX, not add it up. Thanks. ?!

Comment: What assembler are you using? if you want to move instead of add, then use mov eax,node.value[ebx].